# Moving a LINQ sub query to an extension method fails at runtime

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working out this LINQ query in LINQPad. I'm doing something like this:

```
var perms = (from x in db.TableName // etc
            select new ProfilePermission
            { // etc
            });

perms = perms.Concat(from x in db.TableName // etc
            select new ProfilePermission
            { // etc
            });

var results = (from pi in db.AnotherTable
                where pi.IsActive
                select new MyViewModel
                {
                    KeyId = pi.Id,
                    Permissions = (from pm in perms
                                    where pi.ChildId == pm.ChildId
                                    select pm)
                }
```

Using this sub query works. So, I figured, let's move it to an extension method. I tried doing this:

```
public static IQueryable<ProfilePermission> GetProfilePermissions
    (
    this IMkpContext db
    )
{
    var perms = (from x in db.TableName // etc
            select new ProfilePermission
            { // etc
            });

    perms = perms.Concat(from x in db.TableName // etc
            select new ProfilePermission
            { // etc
            });


    return perms;
}

var results = (from pi in db.AnotherTable
                where pi.IsActive
                select new MyViewModel
                {
                    KeyId = pi.Id,
                    Permissions = (from pm in db.GetProfilePermissions()
                                    where pi.ChildId == pm.ChildId
                                    select pm)
                }
```

Now I get a message:

> NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[PublicationSystem.Model.ViewModels.ProfilePermission] GetProfilePermissions(PublicationSystem.Model.IMkpContext)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Why does the sub query work one way, and not the other? I thought that perms ended up as an `IQueryable<>` either way.

Comment: The problem and the solution are explained [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

Comment: I usually just use following : public static object GetProfilePermissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that at the place you've used the extension method, it's not executed, but becomes a part of another expression (`Select` in your case), i.e. is memorized as `MethodCallExpression` to a method that is not recognized by EF query provider.

If you indeed use the extension method in some **top level** query construct like `Join` or `GroupJoin`, it will work. Or if you can move the call outside the query and store the result into a variable.

For instance, in your case the following will work:

```
var results = 
    from pi in db.AnotherTable
    where pi.IsActive
    join pm in db.GetProfilePermissions() on pi.ChildId equals pm.ChildId into permissions
    select new MyViewModel
    {
        KeyId = pi.Id,
        Permissions = permissions
    };
```

as well as this:

```
var permissions = db.GetProfilePermissions();
var results =
    from pi in db.AnotherTable
    where pi.IsActive
    select new MyViewModel
    {
        KeyId = pi.Id,
        Permissions = (from pm in permissions
                        where pi.ChildId == pm.ChildId
                        select pm)
    };
```